# Cancel or Rewrite WHERE Clause in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Can I cancel or rewrite a WHERE condition?

I have the following query...

```
<?php

$userOrUsers = \DB::table('users')->where('id',7);
if(!$userOrUsers->exists()){
    $userOrUsers->where('id','!=',7);
}
$userOrUsers = $userOrUsers->get();

dd($userOrUsers);
```

The query gives me nothing, how can I cancel the last **where** without using two **->get()**?

If id 7 does not exists, then there is no need of where id != 7

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain, it is not understandable

Comment: @akbansa if have this user get him , else get all

Comment: a note: if id 7 does not exists, then there is no need of where id != 7 ?

Comment: @tan yes , correct , and without use two get

Comment: It's not possible to use only one `get` in your scenario, unless you always fetch all users then either selecting or filtering out the specific user in the app code.

Comment: You could `orderByRaw('id = 7')` and check the ID of the first record, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use query as:

```
if($user = \DB::table('users')->find(7)) return $user;
else return \DB::table('users')->all();
```

Comment: condition , don't use two query , or two **get**

Comment: I think we need to check first if record exists or not

Answer (score 0):

You can do some collection operations

```
$userOrUsers = \DB::table('users')->all();

if($userOrUsers->contains('id', 7)) {
$userOrUsers = $userOrUsers->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value->id == 7;
})->all();
};
```